# chrome adEventListner not wotking on notification sound

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am trying to add audio on load notification on chrome.
My Js code below.
it's working fine on firefox but sometimes on chrome it's not running m

error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

```
audio_notice = new Audio('http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3');
     audio_notice.autoplay = true;
    audio_notice.addEventListener('ended', function () {
        try {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.play();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }, false);
    audio_notice.addEventListener('load', function () {
        try {
            this.play();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }, true);
```

[## LIve example ##](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/ohg2y47b/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the event "load" is not correct, it's not in the [list of compatible events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Events).

You can use `loadeddata` instead

```
audio_notice.addEventListener('loadeddata', function () {
    try {
        this.play();
    } catch (e) {
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: i am getting this error for using ur code  this.play();   Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: I found this post on SO, I think it's helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276718/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-the-play-request-was-interru

Comment: I tried here.  https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/ohg2y47b/ it sometimes playing sound sometimes not. may be it's chrome issue. Is there any other way to set autoplay

Comment: @LemonKazi There is a couple of information [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)