# How to play a wav file received from server as response in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, blob, wav

i'm sending a .wav file from server

```
app.use('/audio', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  let file = req.file;
  const destinationPath = await saveFile(req, res, file);
  const text = await stt(destinationPath);
  const reply = await talkToGPT(text);
  const replyAudioPath = await tts(reply);

  res.sendFile(replyAudioPath);
})
```

and i want to play this audio immediately on react client side, i don't know how to do this react please help me out

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/audio", 
  data, 
  config
)
.then((response) => {
    
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please make an attempt at this yourself by searching your question up online, on google, modzilla, etc. before coming here for help. We try to help people with problems in code, not write code for them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Play audio with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602005/play-audio-with-react)

Comment: Why not just send the src URL of the file (in some JSON) and have the client code open that in an audio element? It would be more efficient than downloading the whole file and opening it. You could have a separate button that _does_ download it (without playing it).

Comment: update:                            
     .then((response) => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "audio/wav" });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const audio = new Audio();
        audio.src = url;
        audio.play();
      })                                                                                                                        
this is giving me error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

Comment: @Andy i'm building an assistant on top of chatgpt and i want the reponse/audio to be played without any interaction, that's why can't give a download option

Comment: Ok; re the first part of my comment: is there a reason you need to _download_ the file rather than have an audio element _link_ to a file on the server? @zxcvbnm

Comment: @Andy you're right, i should do the streaming instead